# Mark a local variable safe for any value

Tags: file-local-variables, local-variables, buffer-local, directory-local-variables

The variable [`safe-local-variable-values`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html#Safe-File-Variables) can store name/value pairs that are safe as file-local or directory-local. However sometimes I want to say *any* value is valid for a given variable. The manual page I linked to says that any integer value is considered safe for `fill-column`. Is there a way to do this for my own variables?

Comment: Try using `identity` as test.

Comment: @wasamasa I think (lambda (_) t) is better, for the nil case.

Comment: `(lambda (_) t)` is also predefined as `always`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set the [`safe-local-variable` property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html#index-safe-local-variable) to a function that validates the value. For example, `fill-column` has a `safe-local-variable` property set to `integerp`. Use `(lambda (x) t)` as the validation function if any value is valid.

```
(defvar my-variable-with-any-safe-value …)
(put 'my-variable-with-any-safe-value 'safe-local-variable
     (lambda (x) t))
```

or

```
(defcustom my-variable-with-any-safe-value …
  :safe (lambda (x) t))
```

Having *any* valid value is pretty rare. It's far more common to restrict to a specific type, e.g. `integerp`, `stringp`, etc.